# Кодировка на сайте

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка

В общем? поменял кодировку на сайте (посоветовали, что это к лучшему) на utf-8, сделал следующее.

Файл .htacces:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
charsetdisable on
```

Файл index.php:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Сам код

```
<?php           
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cat ");
    $myrow=mysql_fetch_array($result);          
    $i=1;                   
    do      
    {               
        echo($myrow['title']);      
    }while ($myrow=mysql_fetch_array($result));     
?>
```

В базе MySql кодировка utf8 general ci (в полях, в самой базе, в данных, вообщем везде)
таблица Cat в MySql: написано все по-русски в строках!

И вот? что получилось

[image: снимок]

Все отображает хорошо, кроме менюшки, мучаюсь а результата нет. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы меню заработало? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найдите файл с меню и попробуйте поменять кодировку на utf-8. Советую через notepad++. Возможно в этом проблема.

**Добавлено.**

А если так попробовать `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` (при подключении к базе).

Comment: Сначала именно так и подумал, и поэтому убрал меню, и решил просто в документ вывести информацию, и все равно такая же фигня!

Comment: Добавлено в ответ. Если ответ помог, поставьте плюс. )

Comment: ураааааааааааааа, спасибо! а можете обьяснить вот это mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: Это мы выводим запрос с базы в кодировки utf-8.

Comment: @Node_pro это мы говорим базе, что клиент (мы) работает в юникоде и все данные надо перед выводом конвертировать именно в него, в какой бы там кодировке ни была база. Просто уточнил)

Comment: О спасибо, понял! То есть настройки MySql не имеют значения, если мы напишим эту строку `(mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");)`?

Answer (score 1):

После коннекта к базе данных делайте:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

У вас хоть и кодировка в базе utf-8 но данные туда пишутся в windows-1251

А еще лучше записывать сразу в utf  в таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя сам шаблон с меню сохранен в windows-1251. Открой его и сохрани в utf-8.